# Unity cross script variable editing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Scenario**

So, I have two scripts, "Movement" which handles all the player movement and holds a score variable for the player, this is a component that takes in the player object. Then I have another script for my moving platforms triggers which detects if the ball has passed it or not. When the trigger is activated I want to increase the Score variable in the "Movement". Problem is the error I get is...

**Assets\PlatformTrigger.cs(28,23): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Movement.Score**

Here are the two full scripts in their entirety

**PlatformTrigger.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
   // public GameObject X;

    
    void Start() {

        

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("FDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
        if (col.name == "Player") {
            Movement.Score++;
            Debug.Log(Movement.Score); //ERROR error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Movement.Score'


        }

    }

}
```

**Movement.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float PushForce = 500f;
    Rigidbody Player;
    public static int Score = 0;


  //  List<float> timeArrays = new List<float>();
  //  List<float> distArrays = new List<float>();

   // public float CurrentVelocity { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    //float Vel(float distance)
   // {
   //     if (timeArrays.Count == 2)
      //  {
    //        float TrueTime = timeArrays[1] - timeArrays[0];
    //        float velocity = distance / TrueTime;
     //       return velocity;
    //    }
     //   else { return PushForce; }
//
   // }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //if (timeArrays.Count > 2) { timeArrays.Clear(); }
       // else if (distArrays.Count > 2) { distArrays.Clear(); }

        //else {}

        //float CurrentPos = transform.position.x;

        //Debug.Log(timeArrays.Count);
        //Debug.Log(distArrays.Count);        //Debug.Log(time2 - time1);


        // if (distArrays.Count == 2) {
        //    CurrentVelocity = Vel(distArrays[1] - distArrays[0]);
        //            Debug.Log(CurrentVelocity);
        //    } 

        if (Input.GetKey("right")|| Input.GetKey("d"))
       {
        Player.AddForce(PushForce * Time.deltaTime,0,0);
        //         timeArrays.Add(DateTime.Now.Second);
        //    distArrays.Add(transform.position.x);
        //Debug.Log("Right");

    }

        else if (Input.GetKey("left")|| Input.GetKey("a")){
            Player.AddForce(- PushForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            //timeArrays.Add(DateTime.Now.Second);
            //distArrays.Add(transform.position.x);
            // Debug.Log("Right");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :) I would like to know why this isn't working and a good dumbed down way of what I need to do to fix this, I don't often program in C# and have barely touched unity

Comment: I am assuming that you have the other script in a gameobject. You will need to put that object in a variable and den use scoreObject.GetComponent<Movement>().score++; Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find objects by its name: `GameObject.Find("NameOfYourGameObjectHere").getComponent<NameOfYourScriptHere>().NameOfTheVariableYouWantToAcess = Something;`